# Compile with XeLaTeX in TeXstudio

Tags: errors, compiling, texstudio

I'm working with TexStudio + TexLive 2016, I believe that, among LaTeX editors, TeXstudio has the best user interface, even having a licensed version of WinEdt, I still prefer TeXstudio.

Now I'm compiling with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. The result is OK when I use Winedt or TecnicCenter, but when I use TeXstudio to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=sgvnames,a4paper,12pt,abntfigtabnum,normaltoc,capchap,rm,amstex,t]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Equa\c{c}\~oes Diferenciais Ordinárias}
\author{Raimundo Benedito do Nascimento}
%\date{}                                          

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introdu\c cão}
\section{Preliminares}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.
You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
For immediate help type H <return>.
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please note that this site requires that question (and answer) be written in English.  Your English need not be perfect, of course, but please try to translate your question, if you want to increase your chances of getting an answer

Comment: In any case, your problem seems quite simple, and the error message explains it fully: you are trying to compile your source with `pdflatex`, not with `xelatex`…  But I’m wondering if you can understand my words too…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's (a) caused by using `pdflatex` with `fontspec` (and the error message solves this) and (b) not written in English.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works if you compile it with `Tools > Commands > XeLaTeX`.

I have the Italian version of TeXstudio:

[image]